# Proof of $A \subset B \iff A\cap B=A \iff A \cup B = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to know if this proof is correct or if something needs to change.

I want to prove $A \subset B \iff A\cap B=A \iff A \cup B = B$

If $A \subset B$, then for every $a \in A$, we have $a \in B$ by definition of "$\subset$", thus $a \in A \cap B$. This shows that $A \subset A \cap B$. Now if $a \in A \cap B$ then $a \in A$ by definition of "$\cap$" and thus $A \cap B \subset A$. It follows that $A = A \cap B$.

If $A \cap B = A$, then for every $a \in A$,  we have $a \in A \cap B$ by definition of "$=$" and thus $a \in B$ by definition of "$\cap$". This shows that $A \subset B$.

If $A \cup B = B$ then

$\forall a :: a \in A \cup B \;\equiv\; a \in B $

$\equiv \forall a :: a \in A \lor a \in B \;\equiv\; a \in B $

$\equiv \forall a :: a \in A \;\Rightarrow\; a \in B$

$\equiv A \subset B$

Comment: What does $\equiv$ mean in this context? Is it an $\iff$?

Comment: This is correct

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Perhaps. I'm not sure how to parse$$\forall x :: x \in A \cup B \;\equiv\; x \in B$$if that's the case.

Comment: @TheoBendit I agree that it is a bit of a mess but I think it should mean $$\forall x : x\in A\cup B \iff x\in B$$ And the $\equiv$ between the lines mean "this statement is equivalent to this one"

Comment: Speaking in general, proving $(1)\iff(2)\iff(3)$ may be done by showing $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$, $(2)\Rightarrow(3)$ and finally $(3)\Rightarrow(1)$.

Comment: You've proven $A\subset B\iff A\cap B=A$ and that $A\cup B =B \implies A\subset B$.  (and from those it follows $A\cup B=B\implies A\cap B =A$).  But you haven't proven $A\subset B\implies A\cup B = B$. (or equivalently $A\cap B=A\implies A\cup B = B$).  You need one more "tie" to put it all together.

Comment: Michael Hope:  Or some other "path"  $1\to 2; 1\to 3; 3\to 1;3\to 2$.  Although a three way path is most effective.  The OP has proven $3\implies 1 \iff 2$.  To complete the proof s/he must prove either $1\implies 3$ or $2 \implies 3$.  However that would make one of the proofs (either $1 \implies 2$ or $2\implies 1$) redundant.

Comment: To visualize my comments more clearly:  You have proven $A\cup B=B \implies A\subset B \iff A\cap B = A$.  You need one more step.  (And once you do that, one of your early steps will not actually have been needed.)

Comment: @fleablood So I need to prove $A \subset B \Rightarrow\ A \cup B = B$?

Comment: Yep.  That would do it.  Then you have a $(A\cup B = B \iff A\subset B)$ and $(A\subset B)\iff A\cap B =A$).    But as Michael Hope points out you can be more efficient by proving three things (not 4) if you do $A\subset B \implies A\cap B=A\implies A\cup B= B \implies A \subset B$.  But then again although that fewer things to prove it may be harder to prove $A\cap B=A \implies A\cup B=B$ without going throught $A\subset B$ as an in between step.  And there's no point in knocking yourself out just to follow a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show three implications:

1. $A \subseteq B$ implies $A \cap B = A$: suppose $A$ is a subset of $B$, then note that always $A \cap B \subseteq A$ by definition and $A \subseteq A \cap B$ because $x \in A$ implies $x \in B$ (by $A \subseteq B$) and so $x \in A \cap B$. So both inclusions hold and $A \cap B= A$ is shown.
2. $A \cap B = A$ implies $A \cup B = B$: so we assume the first equality holds, and we'll show the second: $B \subseteq A \cup B$ is trivial. And if $x \in A \cup B$, either $x \in B$ and we're done, or $x \in A = A \cap B$ (assumption) and so $x \in B$ also follows, hence $A \cup B \subseteq B$ and two inclusions give $B = A \cup B$, as required.
3. $A \cup B = B$ implies $A \subseteq B$: assume the equality holds and let $x \in A$. Then also $x \in A \cup B$ so by the assumption $x \in B$: we conclude $A \subseteq B$. That concludes the proof of the final implication.

This shows the three-way equivalence in the usual way.